# Why can't I access to this method?

Tags: java, class, methods

```
package learnclass;

public class Car {

    public String manuName;
    public int engineCC;
    public float fuelammount;
    public float carWeight;

    public float presentAmountFuel(){

        return fuelammount;
    }


}
```

//////////////////////

```
package learnclass;

public class LearningClass {
    static private Car ourCar;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ourCar.

    }

}
```

I just cant access presentAmountFuel() method  by ourCar object . Why is this happening ?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: `ourCar` needs to be instantiated.

Comment: Show the actual code that you're trying to compile, and the exact and complete compiler error message. (My guess is that you don't have any, which means that you can access the method).

Comment: @MAV: I am learning java new . I have created an object of car class . I thought I could access the method of car class via ourCar . what do u mean by instantiated ? can u plz tell me how can I access ?

Comment: What tells you that you cannot access the method? Nothing in the above code tries to access it. `ourCar.` should give a compiler error, but this doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: sorry ,I am learning java new

Comment: @ShuvroShuvro: first rule of programming: read the error message. If you don't understand it, post it.

Answer (score 2):

If your method is not static you have to initialize the object before you can use its methods.

Try following code to access your objects method:

```
package learnclass;

public class LearningClass 
{
    static private Car ourCar;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ourCar = new Car();   // Initialize your object before you can use its method presentAmountFuel()
        ourCar.presentAmountFuel();    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the object.

```
static private Car ourCar = new Car();
```